# Variable in inline table-value function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write an inline table-value function using SSMS v18.2 against SQL Server 2017 with a while loop.

Can I have a way to declare a variable in an inline table-value function for a loop?

If it a yes, what is the syntax for this?

Comment: **[`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

Comment: It might be better to share the problem you're trying to solve. Assuming you can produce a table function running a while loop I suspect the performance of the results will be less than stellar. There may well be better set based approaches that can be taken.

Comment: Inline TVF can only contain a single SELECT statement. WHILE loops are only possible in multi statement (non inline) TVF

Comment: I'm want to ask if there is a way to declare variable in inline table-function. Because i'm want to use a while loop with a variable type int and increasing

Comment: Thanks Martin, may be that is the answer I need

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. The fact that you *want* a loop sounds like a design flaw, or a lack of knowledge of set based solutions. If you show us what you're actually trying to achieve, we can likely show you how to do in with an inline table-value function that doesn't use a `WHILE`..

Comment: *"Because i'm want to use a while loop with a variable type int and increasing"* Don't use a `WHILE to do that; use a tally. That are 1,000 of times faster.

Comment: What is tally? can you give me some link to read more about it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering the comment not the question here, which is *"Because I'm want to use a while loop with a variable type int and increasing"*. Simply, put don't. The best (and i do mean best) way to do this is with a Tally (they are faster than a rCTE as well).

The below will generate the number 1-1,000,000, and will do it in a matter of seconds:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5) --1 Million
SELECT I
FROM Tally;
```

The above is a set based solution, and can be "easily" expanded to work against datasets; for example creating all the dates between 2 dates.

You can also read up on Tallys in this article by Jeff Moden: [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1)

This question doesn't really answer the real problem the OP has, it just introduces them to tally 9and this would not fit in a comment). I would suggest, Hai Nguyen, you ask a new question, explaining your real goals, so that we can help you understand how you can put the above into practice.

Comment: Okay, I got the case. But one more question, can I put the parameter in it?

Comment: Yes, @HaiNguyen . This was a simplified example. See my closing statement.

Comment: Okay, so I need to ask one more question: I have an inline table-value function with a parameter type int. Can I use tally in another function to query the result of the function I have?

Comment: That question is too vague to answer, @HaiNguyen. You should be asking a new question, showing what youn are *really* after; like i have said above a couple a times.

Comment: Okay, let me ask new question.